# The Controller folder is empty after installing the RoadKill wiki engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, open-source, roadkill-wiki

I have installed Roadkill Wiki engine (2.0.275), but i am facing these problems:-

- when i run the project using visual Studio 2012 , i got the following message, on the home page:-

> You have no mainpage set
>       To set a main page, create a page and assign the tag 'homepage' to it.

- Also i have noted that the Controller folder is empty, while the View folder do have sub folders. so do i have to create the controller classes manually ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main page message is from you having no pages created in the Wiki, at least with the "homepage" tag  - that's how Roadkill picks out the homepage page.

The structure of the project is slightly, or infact completely different, from the standard MVC template. All C# code including controllers and models can be found in Roadkill.Core. All views, CSS and Javascript (or Typescript) is found in Roadkill.Web.

So to find the controllers and models, have a look in:

```
Roadkill.Core
    - MVC
        - Controllers
        - Models
```

Comment: but from solution explorer inside visual studio , i can not find the "Core" folder . can you advice please ? thanks

Comment: @johnG Core is a project, and also a folder - Roadkill.Core